# Why can dart be used to write back end server?

Tags: dart

As i know, the advantage of dart seems be writing web apps. So why command line apps are supported too?
For back end code, dart can be better than python, or go?
Google designed dart to be capable of both front and back end code, why?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Dart is a general purpose language. It has been geared towards running in a browser, but nothing prevents it from running on the server. On the contrary: we believe it's a good fit there, too.

There is also the big advantage that programming client and server in the same language allows to reuse code, and avoids the mental context switch.

Comment: I am so grateful to the Dart team that they are making it a general-purpose language! It is a HUGE advantage!

Comment: They said they made it as a general purpose language, and then they said they must focus on dart2js, nothing else. They made cde, they gave up. They made Dart Editor, they gave up too. Keep it as simple as possible and make a long-term decision please !